# Prototype chain printed differently in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

I have a sample program where I test the prototype chain of three objects. When I enter the script in Mozilla, it gives the expected output which is:

```
Object { constructor: John() }
Object { constructor: Employee() }
Object { run: Person.prototype.run(), … }
Object { … }
```

The same program in Chrome gives this output:

```
Employee {constructor: ƒ}
Person {constructor: ƒ}
{run: ƒ, constructor: ƒ}
{constructor: ƒ, __defineGetter__: ƒ, __defineSetter__: ƒ, hasOwnProperty: ƒ, __lookupGetter__: ƒ, …}
```

Why this difference? What is actually happening? Here is the code:

```
function Person() {
    this.age = 15;
    this.year_born = 1996;
}

Person.prototype.run = function () {
    console.log("running");

}

function Employee() {
    Person.call(this);
    this.salary = 600;
}

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;

function John() {
    Employee.call(this);
    this.wife = "Jenny";
}

John.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
John.prototype.constructor = John;

var per = new Person();
var emp = new Employee();
var john = new John();

for (var prot = Object.getPrototypeOf(john); prot != null; prot = Object.getPrototypeOf(prot)) {
    console.log(prot);
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. It's exactly the same prototype chain, it just formats the objects differently

Comment: @Bergi Can you please explain what and why is the difference?

Comment: Because they're different consoles in different developer tools, implemented differently?

Comment: I mean what is te logic behind the output in Chrome, why Employee when it's Object with constructor John?

Comment: Chrome says it's "an Employee object" because it inherits from a prototype object (`Employee.prototype`) whose `.constructor.name` is `Employee`. This is usually more useful for instances, e.g. when you `console.log(john)` it says that it's "a John object".

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have one more question. If i remove the `console.log(prot)` and write `prot` only, I get only one object printed, the last object(`Object.prototype`). Why is this when i loop through the objects?

Comment: Because when you enter code in the console, it does by default print the result value of the last statement that is evaluated (which might be the statement in the loop body). You can also try `for (var i=0; i<10; i++) i;`

Comment: It is clear now. Thanks for your help. You can write the comments as an answer so I can accept it.